# sigmoid function in vb

Tags: vb.net, sigmoid

Can anyone code a simple sigmoid function in vb.net? I have tried and I don't think it works. If anyone could suggest any improvements and/or fixes, I would be very happy. Thanks!

```
        Function sigmoid(inputs As Single)
        Dim finish As New Decimal
        finish = 1 / 1 + 2.71828183 ^(-inputs)
        Return finish
        End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division operator has a higher precendence than the addition operator, so your function is calculating (1/1) + e^-x. All you need to do is add brackets to force the evaluation to be 1/(1+e^-x).

There is a built in e^x function.

There is probably no need to use a Single rather than a Double.

You need to declare the return type of the function - a Double is probably better for what you are using it for than a Decimal. The use of `Option Strict On` would have told you about the former; I strongly recommend that you use it and set it to be the default for new VB projects.

```
Function sigmoid(x As Double) As Double
    Return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x))
End Function
```

Please see [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx) and [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).